# Replace numbers in string with phrase-number

Tags: php, regex, string, preg-replace

In PHP I have a string with a value of something like `1 OR 2` or maybe `1 AND (20 OR 3)`.  I would like to replace those numbers with a phrase followed by the number to make something like `condition1` meaning:

`1 OR 2` => `condition1 OR condition2`

`1 AND (20 OR 3)` => `condition1 AND (condition20 OR condition3)`

I think I can use preg_replace to do this but I can't figure out how.  I'm having a difficult time preserving the value of the numbers during the replacement.

If it makes it easier I will also accept an answer in javascript

Comment: humm... can you give an example of a sentence?

Comment: preg_replace is acceptable, but I can't figure out how to use it correctly to do what I need

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the arguments to the operators are the only numbers in the string, you can do:

```
$new = preg_replace( '/(\d+)/', 'condition$1', $input);
```

This matches any successive number of digits, and captures them in a capturing group, which we reference later in the replacement as `$1`.

You can see from [this demo](http://viper-7.com/I1ycTe) that for your test cases, this outputs:

```
condition1 OR condition2
condition1 AND (condition20 OR condition3)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use 
    str_replace($search, $replace, $string)

```
$search can be array whatever you want to replace
$replace can alse be an array wherever you want to replace in a string
$string is a string where you want to change
```

is it solution of your problem or you want something else?